# Error - Create database connection in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I am having trouble when I try to create a database connection in eclipse.

I created a connection to Sql server 2008. Database name, host, port, username, password, driver: sqljdbc ... everything is true. I ping successfully.
But when I see my connection, it shows all my databases and the hibernate tool cant see any table in database.

You can see in this picture

[image: Database Connections tree showing that the DBs and tables exist]

Comment: Have you created tables in your database?

Comment: Yes, i did it, u can see in picture, tables are tbladmin, tblFeedback,..

Comment: Can you provide the code and connection string you are using to connect to the database?